# Deleting a column of rows in excel above a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a very novice programmer at the moment, but I'm dealing with an excel spreadsheet I need to delete rows out of.

eg.

```
<1>
Title 1
xyz
Title 2
xyz
Title 3
xyz
xyz
xyz
Title 4
xyz
```

Each line is on a new row in Excel and there are about 1412 of these. I would need to remove some of the titles and content, but keep others. With the code below that I've found and modified, I've been able to remove titles with single lines of content, but I can't make it work on titles with multiple lines of content, eg. Title 3 and the 3 lines of content below it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

---

```
Sub removeSingleRows()

Const strTOFIND As String = "Title 1"

    Dim rngFound As Range, rngToDelete As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheet1.Range("A:A")
        Set rngFound = .Find( _
                            What:=strTOFIND, _
                            Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=True)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToDelete = rngFound

            strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address

            Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)

            Do Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
                Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
            Loop
        End If
    End With

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
    rngToDelete.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this which

- loops through an array of words to be found
- updates the range logic for multiple searches

**code**

```
Sub removeSingleRows()

Dim strArr()
Dim strArrE
Dim rngFound As Range
Dim rngToDelete As Range
Dim strFirstAddress As String

strArr = Array("Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each strArrE In strArr
    With Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
        Set rngFound = .Find(CStr(strArrE), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, True)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
            Set rngToDelete = rngFound
            Else
            Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
            End If
            strFirstAddress = rngFound.Address
            Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
            Do Until rngFound.Address = strFirstAddress
                Set rngToDelete = Application.Union(rngToDelete, rngFound)
                Set rngFound = .FindNext(After:=rngFound)
            Loop
        End If
    End With
    Set rngFound = Nothing
 Next

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
    rngToDelete.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
    rngToDelete.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a fantastic improvement and would save quite a bit of time entering the Titles manually one by one and executing the code.
Unfortunately, one of the original problems still remains, I can't get the long list of content under Title 3 to be deleted. With this code, it will delete the Title, and the first xyz and the rest remain.

Comment: Is there anything that distinguishes when the content under the Titles finishes, and the next Title begins?

Comment: Yep, all the content is indented by 2 or 4 spaces.

Comment: so the first two/four charcaters are blank?

Comment: Yep, first two or four characters are blank for content rows.

Comment: If @brettdj 's response helped, please accept his answer, so your question will show up as "answered."